# Opensuse Stop Gnome Zoom from Following typing

Tags: linux, gnome, opensuse, accessibility, zoom

I'm currently running Opensuse 42.1 Leap.

I have a visual disability so I use the Zoom functionality built into Gnome's Universal Access tools.

I love the zoom function, except for one problem. As I type, apparently only while using a terminal, the center of the screen snaps to the area where I'm typing. It follows as I type each character. This is incredibly annoying and I cannot seem to find any way to stop this from happening.

I've looked everywhere for an answer, but when it comes to things regarding accessibility, there are very few answers.

If anyone could help, I would really appreciate it.